# Incorrect notice regarding Developer Stories

Tags: bug

I received a notice about the demise of Developer Stories, with the notation "You're receiving this email because you have a Developer Story on Stack Overflow."

But I don't.

So I'm guessing you are confusing lots of people. :-)

Comment: You do have one: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1569967 It's just hidden so you may have forgotten about it.

Comment: Do you have anything under "Settings" > "Developer Story preferences"?

Comment: Nope... at least nothing that seems significant. But thanks... I didn't know I had Settings till now.

Answer (score 5):

Paraphrasing from animuson's comment:

If you receive a notice, but you don't think you have a Developer Story, then double-check that [your developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current) isn't hidden from public view.

If you *really* don't have a developer story and you somehow got a notice, that is worthy of a separate bug report.

Comment: How do I navigate to my developer story? When I click on my profile I don't see any mention of this.

Comment: Use your unique user ID (in your case @monty0 it'd be https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1373521) to confirm if it exists or not.  I'm getting a 404 back so there's a 50-50 chance it's hidden.

Comment: "current" can be used instead of a specific user id to navigate to the page associated with the currently logged-in account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current

Comment: Call me crazy, but not having a story and having a hidden one, which I can't see and can't unhide, seem to be functionally equivalent from the user perspective.

Comment: You're crazy, @Charlie.  The visibility of data is not the absence of data.  This is why soft-deletion is such a privacy issue.

Comment: @Charlie If it helps, when I go to Henry’s link, I get a message about how it is no longer possible to create a Developer Story. Do you get that or the 404?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, that's what I get and it's all that I get. The accepted answer says "double-check that your developer story isn't hidden" but there's no info either on the page or in the answer itself as to how one might do that. In any case, I apologize for offending folks who thought they designed a clear message. :-)